# Crawler script does not want to display the links on the console with nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I try to have all the links for each car version. All goes well until the 3rd "Request" which when I run it in the console does not show anything. I don't know why. Can you help me please?

```
var request = require('request');
var fetch=require('node-fetch');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url="http://www.auto-selection.com/fiche-technique/alfa-romeo/";
console.log('starting');

request(url, function(err, resp, html) {
  // Si il n'y a pas d'erreur afficher le code html de l'url
  if (!err){
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var link_model = $(".color3 a");
    $(link_model).each(function (i, link) {
        var link_models = $(this).attr('href');

        // console.log(link_models);
        request(link_models, function(err, resp, html){
          if(!err){
              var $= cheerio.load(html);
              var link_model_year = $(".color3 a");
              $(link_model_year).each(function (index, link) {
                  var links_models_years = $(this).attr('href');
                  // console.log(links_models_years);
                  request(links_models_years, function (err,resp,html) {
                      if(!err){
                          var $= cheerio.load(html);
                          var link_model_version = $(".sorting_1 a");
                          $(link_model_version).each(function () {
                              var links_models_versions = $(this).attr('href');
                              console.log(links_models_versions)
                          });

                      }
                  })

              });

          }
        });

    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no `.sorting_1` class in the loaded page - it is added only after the page scripts are executed. But `cheerio` [`does not produce a visual rendering, apply CSS, load external resources, or execute JavaScript`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#cheerio-is-not-a-web-browser).

So you need to use another pattern to search for links. For example this:

```
var link_model_version = $("#AsFTList a");
```